# Prove: for $x$ large enough, there are more primes in the interval $(1,x]$ than in $(x,2x]$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I want to show that there are more primes in the interval $(1,x]$ than in $(x,2x]$, when $x$ is large enough. Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function, ie. $\pi(x)=\# \{ p \leq x | p \text{ is a prime} \}$. Then the above statement is equivalent to showing:

$\pi (2x)-2\pi(x)=-\log(2)\frac{x}{\log ^2x}+O\left(\frac{x}{\log ^3 x}\right)$

I have a hint saying to use the prime number theorem. I'm trying to use that $\pi(x)= \frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{\log ^2 x} + O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^3 x} \right)$, but can't seem to rewrite it fitting. Maybe I need to use other aspects of the prime number theorem.

Added: It's useful to see alternative ways of solving the problem, but I'm still specifically seeking to show the equation above using PNT.

Comment: Can you use the prime number theorem for $\pi(2x)$?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. I use the prime number theorem stated in H. L. Montgomery and R. C. Vaughan. Multiplicative number theory. I. Additionally to what I wrote in the question it states that $\psi(x)=x+O \left( \frac{x}{exp(c \sqrt{\log x})} \right)$ and $\pi(x)=li(x) + O \left( \frac{x}{exp(c \sqrt{\log x})} \right) $. for $x \geq2$

Comment: Does it help to say $\pi(2x)=\dfrac{2x}{\log 2x}+\cdots$?

Comment: Maybe, but I can't really get any further from there :(

Comment: I get sometihing like this:

$\pi(2x)-2\pi(x) = \frac{2x}{\log 2x} + \frac{2x}{\log ^2 2x} + O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^3 2x} \right) 
    - 2 \left( \frac{x}{\log x} + \frac{x}{\log ^2 x} + O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^3 x} \right) \right)
    = \frac{2x}{\log 2x} + \frac{2x}{\log ^2 2x} +  O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^3 2x} \right)
    -  \frac{2x}{\log x} - \frac{2x}{\log ^2 x} - O \left( \frac{x}{\log ^3 x} \right)$

Comment: Isn't the prime number theorem just $\pi(x)\sim \dfrac x{\ln x}$?  And you want to show that $\pi(2x)-2\pi(x)<0$, right?  Now $\dfrac{2x}{\ln 2x}-2\dfrac x{\ln x}\sim $ $\dfrac {2x}{\ln x}\left(\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln x}}\right)-\dfrac{2x}{\ln x}\sim$ $\dfrac{2x}{\ln x}\left(1-\dfrac{ \ln2 }{\ln x}+\dfrac{(\ln 2)^2}{(\ln x)^2}...\right)-\dfrac{2x}{\ln x}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I don't think the basic Prime Number Theorem is strong enough to prove what the OP wants. If you try and make your derivation precise, it falls apart. (It did for me, anyway.)

Comment: @TonyK:  I could believe that

Answer (score 1):

From Dusart we know that $\frac{x}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln x} \right) < \pi(x )<\frac{x}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{1.3}{\ln x} \right) $ for all $x \geq 600$ and so you need to prove that $\pi(2x) -2 \pi(x) \leq \frac{2x}{\ln 2x} \left(1+\frac{1.3}{\ln 2x} \right)-2\frac{x}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln x} \right) << 0  $

Or Equivalently $\frac{1}{\ln 2x} \left(1+\frac{1.3}{\ln 2x} \right) << \frac{1}{\ln x}\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln x} \right) => \ln x (1+\frac{1.3}{\ln 2x}) < (\ln x +\ln 2)(1+\frac{1}{\ln x}) => \ln x +\frac{1.3 \ln x}{\ln 2x} < ln x +1.3< \ln x+ 1 + \ln 2 < \ln x+1+\ln 2 + \frac{\ln 2}{\ln x} $

Checking for smaller cases the inequality is true for all $x\geq 11$

Answer (score 0):

From the proof of the prime number theorem by the de la Vallée Poussin we have
$$\frac{x}{\log -(1-\epsilon)} < \pi(x) < \frac{x}{\log x -(1+\epsilon)}$$
for $x\ge x_{\epsilon}$. In other words, if we write $\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x - B(x)}$, then $B(x) \to 1$ ( see [Legendre's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant)).  In fact, we do have an explicit estimate of [Dusart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), but the above is enough.

We get
$\pi(2 x) < \frac{2x}{\log(2x) -(1+\epsilon)}$
and $\frac{2x}{\log x- (1-\epsilon) } < 2\pi(x)$
so we should have
$$\log (2x) -(1+\epsilon) > \log x - (1-\epsilon)$$
or $\log 2 > 2 \epsilon$. So we should take $\epsilon < \frac{\log 2}{2}$, and then get the inequality for $x \ge x_{\epsilon}$.

Note that in general for every $M>1$, we can get $\pi(Mx) < M \pi(x)$ for $x> \bar x_{M}$.

$\bf{Added:}$  Let us use the explicit Dusart bounds
$$\frac{x}{\log x -1} < \pi(x)$$
for $x\ge 5393$, and
$$\pi(x) < \frac{x}{\log x -1.1}$$
for $x \ge 60184$.  Therefore, for $x\ge 30 092$ we get
$$\pi(2x)< \frac{2x}{\log (2x) - 1.1} < \frac{2x}{\log x -1}< 2\pi(x)$$

Consider for  integer $4\le x \le 60183$,  the values of $\frac{\pi(x)}{ 2\pi(x/2)}$. It reaches $1$ at $4$, $7$, $8$, $9$, $13$, $19$, $20$, $21$, and values $< 1$ otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

There is *no need* for error estimates.  Use the PNT in the form $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$. That implies $\pi(2x)/\pi(x) \sim (2x/\log(2x))/(x/\log x) = 2(\log x)/\log(2x)$.  Now convince yourself that this tends to $2$ as $x\to \infty$, so the difference
$$
\pi(2x) - \pi(x) = \pi(x)\left(\frac{\pi(2x)}{\pi(x)} - 1\right)
$$
is large for large $x$.  Similar reasoning shows for each $c > 1$ that $\pi(cx) - \pi(x)$ is large for large $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought OP wanted to show that $\pi(2x)-\pi(x)<\pi(x)$ or $\pi(2x)<2\pi(x)$, and I don't see how that follows from what you said

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  ah, you are correct!  I had misread the question.